# Bernoulli theorem on surface of rotating liquid

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, bernoulli-equation

I have a problem in which I have to find the max height of liquid column:

[image]

This problem can be done by other ways but by trying the Bernoulli theorem I having a problem.

At point z and h the pressure is same 'P' i.e. atmospheric pressure and z has 0 velocity. But velocity at h is coming to be negative. Is there anything I am missing?

```
P+0+0=P+dgh+dv^2/2

Which gives v^2=-2gh
Gives: h=-v^2/2g
```

Comment: You can't use Bernoulli principle. Here a link to a .pdf of notes and exercises about Fluid Mechanics (only Italian). You find this exercise solved at pag. 145, ex. 6.8 https://gitlab.com/davideMontagnani/fluidmechanics-ita/-/blob/master/template/mainEse.pdf?ref_type=heads

Comment: Hint: The solution can be found by analysing the conditions for the liquid to be static in the corotating frame.

Comment: Rephrasing @SebastianRiese, you could assume that the fluid performs rigid rotation, so you know the velocity field. Then you can use the Navier--Stokes equations in cylindrical coordinates (you find them in the .pdf) and integrate pressure in the depth (unknown) using the ambient pressure as the boundary condition on the free surface

Answer (score 1):

Remember that when the motion is not irrotational, Bernoulii can only be appled along streamlines. So you can't use it to relate the height and velocity in this setup.